# How to set rule Style cop for resharper comment all public methods/classes/properties etc

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, resharper, stylecop

I need to have rule for comment all public methods/classes/properties etc. 
I can`t found any standard rule for my requirements.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

StyleCop can *partially* meet what you're after by rules SA1600 to SA1608 (Element Documentation), but they're not based on accessibility so it applies to all your private methods/classes/properties as well. You can either go down this path and document everything otherwise you'll need to write a custom StyleCop rule: http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-custom-stylecop-rules-in-c.html